# How to replace number to string in python

Tags: python

I am tring to convert all the independent number to number's vocabulary in a given string,for example (I have 10 apples and 0 pencil) need to be converted to (I have 10 apples and zero pencil).
However, I cannot directly assign string in list object, please help me, thanks!
Here is my code, I am not very familier with python, thanks guys!

```
s = input()

for i in range(len(s)):
    if(s[i] == '0'):
        s[i] = "zero"
print(s)
```

Comment: `s.replace("0", "zero")`

Comment: Thanks but how to remain 10 as 10

Comment: why `10` not convert to `ten`?

Answer (score 4):

Try with:

```py
s.replace(" 0 ", " zero ")
```

Comment: It doesn't work if `"0"` is at the beginning like `"0 apple"` or at the end like "number of pencil is 0".

Answer (score 4):

You can use regular expression for this:

```
import re

txt = "I have 10 apples and 0 pencil"
x = re.sub(r"\b0\b", "zero", txt)
print(x)
```

this code gives you the output: `I have 10 apples and zero pencil`

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way is use of string replace function:

```
s = 'I have 10 apples and 0 pencil'
print (s.replace(' 0 ',' zero '))
```

The complicated way would be using re (you can use other ways to reach your desired string to be replaced):

```
import re
s = 'I have 10 apples and 0 pencil'
y = re.sub(r'( 0 )', ' zero ', s, count=1, flags=re.IGNORECASE)
print(y)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    s = input()
    print(s.replace("0", "zero"))
```

Comment: This code also changes 10 to 1zero which is not what the OP wants.